# How can I define Option Partial in typescript?

Tags: typescript

```
export type PartialOption<T,K extends string[]> = {[P in K]?: T[P]}
type Student = PartialOption<People, ['age', 'type']>
// So Student will like this
{
 age?: number,
 type?: string,
 name: string
...
}
```

My typescript version: "typescript": "^3.1.2",
How can I define PartialOption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use a union type instead of a tuple type.

```
 export type PartialOption<T,K extends keyof T> = {[P in K]?: T[P]} 
 type Student = PartialOption<People, 'age' | 'type'>
```

In fact this is actually equivalent to the bultin `Partial` type used with `Pick<T, K>`.

If you want to make just some properties optional you can use `Partial` to mark the optional properties and `Pick` to extract the rest of the properties without changing their optinality

```
 export type PartialOption<T,K extends keyof T> = Partial<Pick<T, K>> & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>
 type Student = PartialOption<People, 'age' | 'type'>
```